# Why are we not to throw these exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I came across [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions) that states:

> Do not throw [Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception), [SystemException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.systemexception), [NullReferenceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception), or [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception) intentionally from your own source code.

Unfortunately, it does not bother to explain why. I can guess the reasons but I hope that someone more authoritative on the subject might offer their insight.

The first two make some obvious sense, but the latter two seem like ones you would want to employ (and in fact, I have).

Further, are these the only exceptions one should avoid? If there are others, what are they and why should they, too, be avoided?

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx: If you throw a general exception type, such as Exception or SystemException in a library or framework, it forces consumers to catch all exceptions, including unknown exceptions that they do not know how to handle.

Comment: Why would you throw a NullReferenceException?

Comment: @Rik: similar to `NullArgumentException` which some people might confuse both.

Comment: Surely to throw a System.NullReferenceException you're testing for null - in which case it isn't an exception?

Comment: @Rik extension methods, as per my answer

Comment: Another one you shouldn't throw is [`ApplicationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I would've thought that NullReferenceException and IndexOutOfRangeException would be perfectly fine to throw within a class or library intended to be used by others. For instance, if you create a class that overrides the indexer, throw an IndexOutOfRangeException for bad indexes?

Comment: @Bob IndexOutOfRangeException is specific to array. If you declare an indexer and the user pass an argument out of range, you should throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException (see `List<T>`).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

[`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) is the base type for all exceptions, and as such terribly unspecific. You shouldn’t ever throw this exception because it simply does not contain any useful information. Calling code catching for exceptions couldn’t disambiguate the intentionally thrown exception (from your logic) from other system exceptions that are entirely undesired and point out real faults.

The same reason also applies to [`SystemException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception.aspx). If you look at the list of derived types, you can see a huge number of other exceptions with very different semantics.

[`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) and [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) are of a different kind. Now these are very specific exceptions, so throwing them *could* be fine. However, you still won’t want to throw these, as they usually mean that there are some actual mistakes in your logic. For example the null reference exception means that you are trying to access a member of an object which is `null`. If that’s a possibility in your code, then you should always explicitly check for `null` and throw a more useful exception instead (for example [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx)). Similarly, `IndexOutOfRangeException`s occur when you access an invalid index (on arrays—not lists). You should always make sure that you don’t do that in the first place and check the boundaries of e.g. an array first.

There are a few other exceptions like those two, for example [`InvalidCastException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) or [`DivideByZeroException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception.aspx), which are thrown for specific faults in your code and usually mean that you are doing something wrong or you are not checking for some invalid values first. By throwing them knowingly from your code, you are just making it harder for the calling code to determine whether they were thrown due some fault in the code, or just because you decided to reuse them for something in your implementation.

Of course, there are some exceptions (hah) to these rules. If you are building something that may cause an exception which exactly matches an existing one, then feel free to use that, especially if you are trying to match some built-in behavior. Just make sure you choose a very specific exception type then.

In general though, unless you find a (specific) exception that fills your need, you should always consider creating your own exception types for specific expected exceptions. Especially when you are writing library code, this can be very useful to separate the exception sources.

Comment: The third part makes little sense to me. Sure, you should rather avoid causing these errors to begin with, but when you e.g. write an `IList` implementation, it's not in your power to affect the indices requested, it's *the caller's* logic mistake when an index is invalid, and you are can only inform them of this logic error by throwing an appropriate exception. Why is `IndexOutOfRangeException` not appropriate?

Comment: @delnan If you are implementing `IList`, then you will be throwing a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` as the [interface documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.item.aspx) suggests. `IndexOutOfRangeException` is for arrays, and as far as I know, you can’t re-implement arrays.

Comment: What might also be somewhat related, `NullReferenceException` is usually internally thrown as a special case of an `AccessViolationException` (IIRC the test is something like `cmp [addr], addr`, ie. it tries to dereference the pointer and if it fails with an access violation, it handles the difference between NRE and AVE in the resulting interrupt handler). So apart from semantic reasons, there's also some cheating involved. It might also help discourage you from checking for `null` manually when it's not helpful - if you're going to throw a NRE anyway, why not let .NET do it?

Comment: In regard to your last statement, about custom exceptions:  I have never felt the need to do this.  Perhaps I'm missing out on something.  Under what conditions would one need to craft a custom exception type in lieu of something from the framework?

Comment: Well, for smaller applications there might not be a need for it. But as soon as you create something more complex where individual parts work as independent “components” it often makes sense to introduce custom exceptions for custom error situations. For example, if you have some access control layer, and you try to execute some service although you are not authorized to do so, you might throw a custom “access denied exception” or something. Or if you have a parser that parses some file, you might have your own parser errors to report back to the user.

Comment: Personally, I like to make custom exceptions that contain addition information, so that when they get written to the error log they give me more idea of the context of the error than a stack trace alone can give me (and I override ToString to include this data). If you have to troubleshoot something on a customer's install, this extra information can be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 39):

I suspect the intent with the last 2 is to prevent confusion with inbuilt exceptions that have an expected meaning. However, I'm of the opinion that *if you are preserving the exact intent of the exception*: it is the correct one to `throw`. For example, if you are writing a custom collection, it seems entirely reasonable to use `IndexOutOfRangeException` - clearer and more specific, IMO, than `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. And while `List<T>` might choose the latter, there are *at least* 41 places (courtesy of reflector) in the BCL (not including arrays) that throw bespoke `IndexOutOfRangeException` - none of which are "low level" enough to deserve special exemption. So yeah, I think you can justly argue that that guideline is silly. Likewise, `NullReferenceException` is kinda useful in extension methods - if you want to preserve the semantic that:

```
obj.SomeMethod(); // this is actually an extension method
```

throws a `NullReferenceException` when `obj` is `null`.

Comment: "if you are preserving the exact intent of the exception" - surely if that were the case the exception would be thrown without you having to test for it in the first place?  And if you've already tested for it, then it's not really an exception?

Comment: @PugFugly take 2 seconds to look at the extension method example: no, that will not be thrown without you having to test for it. If `SomeMethod()` doesn't need to perform member access, it is incorrect to force it to. Likewise: take that point up with the 41 places in the BCL that create custom `IndexOutOfRangeException`, and the 16 places that create custom `NullReferenceException`

Comment: I can see what you're saying with the extension method, it's hard to argue that throwing a NullReferenceExample isn't helpful, although when you know extension methods work you may think otherwise.  Returning a NullArgumentException from the extension method more accurately represents what actually happened.  I don't know what BCL is so can't comment on that...

Comment: I would argue that an extension method should still throw a `ArgumentNullException` instead of a `NullReferenceException`. Even if the syntactic sugar from extension methods allows the same syntax as normal member access, it still works very differently. And getting a NRE from `MyStaticHelpers.SomeMethod(obj)` would be just wrong.

Comment: @PugFugly BCL is “base class library”, basically the core stuff in .NET.

Comment: I expect that at least some of the places that throw IndexOutOfRangeException in the BCL, does it as the “old versions” of the code used an array that throw IndexOutOfRangeException, so the new code was made to throw the same exception.

Comment: @PugFugly: There are many scenarios where failing to preemptively detect a condition would result in an exception being thrown at an "inconvenient" time.  If an operation isn't going to succeed, throwing an exception early is better than starting the operation, getting halfway through, and then having to clean up the resulting partially-processed mess.

Comment: Bit of an abstruse point, but if functions that explicitly check for null always throw `ArgumentNull`, and functions that don't explicitly check end up "naturally" throwing `NullReference` on using the null, then aren't you leaking implementation details? Admittedly it's no worse than any situation where you don't fanatically document all exceptions your code can possibly throw and their reasons, but this might lead to some inelegant backward-compatibility requirements if both are possible from the same function. Such as what Ian Ringrose says. That leads me to agree with this answer!

Comment: @SteveJessop: There should be a difference between an exception a caller receives because the caller it passed invalid data to method `foo`, versus an exception the caller receives because--despite the caller's having supplied valid data--some method called by `foo` threw an exception `foo` wasn't expecting.  Reserving NRE and IOORE for system use would mean that if those particular exceptions bubble up they represent "unexpected" conditions, but most exceptions that could represent "expected" conditions may also represent unexpected conditions, and there's no clean way to distinguish them.

Comment: I think we're talking cross purposes here.  If you throw a NullReferenceException by testing for null then the action that causes a NullReferenceException hasn't actually happened.  Sure, it was about to happen but that's different, it didn't actually happen. So I think technically it is incorrect to manually throw them.  However, I agree that it's helpful and would have no problem doing it.

Comment: @PugFugly I cannot entirely disagree.  You seem to be hitting on some grey area.  Throw it because I can see it coming, or let it be thrown because it does happen?

Comment: @PugFugly: Suppose code said `if (foo == null && randomCoinIsHeads()) throw new NullReferenceException(); else foo.DoSomething();`  If `foo` is null, is there any reason why anything should care about the coin flip?  The only advantage I can see to ANE is that it can include a more helpful message than a system-thrown NRE, though I would think a compiler could auto-generate code to make a "real" NRE be just as helpful [Java bytecode could, given an expression foo.bar.boz, have the dereference of `bar` in one catch block and the dereference of `boz` in another; I expect CIL could too]

Answer (score 9):

As you point out, in the article [Creating and Throwing Exceptions (C# Programmming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx) under the topic **Things to Avoid When Throwing Exceptions**, Microsoft does indeed list `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` as an exception type that should not be thrown intentionally from your own source code.

In contrast, however, in the article [throw (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx), Microsoft seems to violate its own guidelines. Here is a method that Microsoft included in its example:

```cs
static int GetNumber(int index)
{
    int[] nums = { 300, 600, 900 };
    if (index > nums.Length)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
    return nums[index];
}
```

So, Microsoft itself isn't being consistent as it demonstrates the throwing of `IndexOutOfRangeException` in its documentation for `throw`!

This leads me to believe that at least for the case of `IndexOutOfRangeException`, there may be occasions where that exception type ***can*** be thrown by the programmer and be considered an acceptable practice.

Comment: Isn't this 100% horrible code to put out in docs/articles i.e. what about: 

GetNumber(3); 

i.e. index == nums.Length 

Suggests at least some people writing MS docs are not clear about indexes starting at 0 and .Length == the number of items, this is not a good indicator of quality IMHO.

(N.B. think this example is not not there anymore but... still)

Comment: if (index >= nums.Length) would have made a bit more sense!

Answer (score 3):

Putting the discussion about `NullReferenceException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` aside:

What about catching and throwing `System.Exception`. I've thrown this type of exception in my code a lot and I was never screwed by it. Similarly, very often I catch the unspecific `Exception` type, and it also worked pretty well for me. So, why is that?

Usually users argue, that they should be able to distinguish error causes. From my experience, there are just a very few situations where you would want to handle different exception types differently. For those cases, where you expect users to handle errors programmatically, you should throw a more specific exception type. For other cases, I'm not convinced by the general best practice guideline.

So, regarding throwing `Exception` I don't see a reason to prohibit this in all cases.

EDIT: also from the MSDN page:

> Exceptions should not be used to change the flow of a program as part of ordinary execution. Exceptions should only be used to report and handle error conditions.

Overdoing catch clauses with individual logic for different exception types are not best practice, either.

Comment: The exception message is still in place to tell what happened. I can't image, that you go and create a new exception type for each different error, just in case a consumer might want to distinguish those errors, programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

When I read your question, I asked myself under what conditions one would want to throw the exception types `NullReferenceException`, `InvalidCastException` or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

In my opinion, when encountering one of those exception types, I (the developer) feel concerned by the warning in the sense that the compiler is talking to me. So, allowing you (the developer) to throw such exception types is equivalent to (the compiler) selling the responsibility. For instance, this suggests the compiler should now allow the developer to decide whether an object is `null`. But making such a determination should really be the job of the compiler.

PS: Since 2003 I have been developing my own exceptions so I can throw them as I wish. I think it is considered a best practice to do so.

Comment: Good points. However, I think it would be more accurate to say that the programmer should let the .NET Framework runtime throw these types of exceptions (and that the programmer should handle them in an appropriate fashion).