# Why is there a `.constrained` opcode preceeding the `call` opcode when calling an abstract static function?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

When I compile this simple C# code:

```
public interface ITestable {
    public abstract static void Test();
}

public class MyTester<T> where T : ITestable {
    public void RunTest() {
        T.Test();
    }
}
```

I get the following three IL opcodes for `MyTester<T>.RunTest()`:

```
IL_0000: constrained. !T
IL_0006: call void ITestable::Test()
IL_000b: ret
```

This doesn't seem to align with what [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained?view=net-7.0) says about the constrained prefix, stating it can only appear before a `callvirt` instruction, but here it's before a `call`. You can see this on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEBlAFgQwCcAHAGXwCMA6AJQFcA7YMAWwFMBuVVGAZkzBM2hAGb4Axm0wBJACpsAzsEoQpAb1SYtmPpkpLCE4DoQA2HQBZM8pQAoAlFxQBfbmn7xMAWQCeN4MIAPLIAfJgA7rjCUrKYIDL+Kuqa2rowVvQM/g6YGijaBdZU2Y4pWq4ubkA===).

This `.constrained` prefix seems to translate in the jitted assembly too. Using SharpLab's `JitGeneric` to compile `MyTester` for a given generic argument (see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACAygCzACcAHAGTACMA6AJQFcA7YASygFMBuddOAZmwtm7IgDMwAY3bYAkgBV2EYFQA20gN7ps27P2xUlRScF1IAbLoAs2BUoAUASm5oAvjzQBtAFItgAcXZGERYJO2AATxJ2AHtROwBZcNtlSjUHBwBdXgFEbETkkQAeOQA+bAB3fBFpOWwQWWTVDS0dPThrBkZkx2xNNB0Bm2pupxbtN1d3NoQ8pMUUtXr5eabegbHdHPMrG3mevsHWpABOOwAiAAl2FRVogEIz0f6dCYn0IA)), the assembly seems to be performing a check before it calls the `Test` function. I was under the impression that static abstract method calls should compile to a simple `call` because the compiler can tell exactly what function is being called, and I don't understand why it is more complex than that.

Comment: I bet because the documentation for the op code was written before the existence of static abstract interface members which basically allows [static interface members to be declared virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces#interface-members) .

Comment: If you make the method non-static you will see that it becomes `.constrained .callvirt` ([@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEBlAFgQwCcAHAGXwCMA6AJQFcA7YMAWwFMBuVASQBU2AzsEoQ2mAB6YAvJgZsA7pgCyAT35CRbABQBKLilQwAzJjBM2hAGb4AxmL6DhFUZgDeqTJ8zHvAFkzqwLr6AL6oqADaAFJgwADibHKEYDZawCrEbAD2llqqgZo6OgC6kTHxiRYpaRnZufmOmghFpWgm8MpqjhYAPLwAfJjyuBZivJggmA4azmLuKF7e7f70DIG6bh6LXuOSMgAmbNZ0EMD6217iVOt6W55hKA+G7XCdBbOT004urot3S54YP4bpsFl4Hk82pghIQ6DZgG9GrMEJ93j8/mDASY/AFHBt5osIeEUEA==)).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with "the compiler can tell exactly what function is being called" because it feels almost exactly the opposite to me - that we know a type matches the interface but we don't know if that type has the static method or just has one higher up its own inheritance chain.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is true when compiling to CIL, as the compiler cannot yet know what type interface will be put into the generic parameter. But I am under the impression that when the CIL gets JITed, a different version of the method will be created for each generic parameter it's used with. At that time, given the generic parameter is known, shouldn't the abstract virtual method being called be certain?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, I suspect that is what's happened here too, but I still don't understand what it's actually checking in this case (and especially why that check is present at runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was under the impression that static abstract method calls should compile to a simple call because the compiler can tell exactly what function is being called, and I don't understand why it is more complex than that.

You should note one thing - for reference types the generics are compiled only once(compared to the value types, where for every one passed as generic parameter the separate implementation will be compiled) to prevent code bloat (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380270/c-sharp-generics-code-bloat-should-i-be-worried) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlos/net-generics-and-code-bloat-or-its-lack-thereof)) and the same compiled code is used for all reference types used as generic type parameter, so compiler does not actually know exactly which function being called.

If you update your second snippet with several value and reference types (note that implementations are a bit different so the difference becomes more clear):

```cs
[JitGeneric(typeof(MyTestable))]
[JitGeneric(typeof(MyTestable11))]
[JitGeneric(typeof(MyTestable1))]
[JitGeneric(typeof(MyTestable2))]
public class MyTester<T> where T : ITestable {
    public void RunTest() {
        T.Test();
    }
}

public class MyTestable: ITestable {    
    public static void Test() =>Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
public class MyTestable11: ITestable {    
    public static void Test() =>Console.Write("Hello!");
}

public struct MyTestable1: ITestable {    
    public static void Test() =>Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}

public struct MyTestable2: ITestable {    
    public static void Test() =>Console.Write("Hello!");
}
```

You will see that for all reference types the same `` MyTester`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].RunTest() `` is emmited while for value types you will have separate ones:

```
MyTester`1[[MyTestable1, _]].RunTest()
    L0000: mov ecx, [0x8d2daa0]
    L0006: call dword ptr [0x10a29ac8]
    L000c: ret

MyTester`1[[MyTestable2, _]].RunTest()
    L0000: mov ecx, [0x8d2daa0]
    L0006: call dword ptr [0x10a29cc0]
    L000c: ret
```

[Code @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

As for the question in title - my guess is that docs were not updated to support the introduction of the static abstract methods in the interfaces (note - the docs are not always correct, even I have bumped into several such cases - for example [github PR 1](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/8228), [github PR 2](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/33589), [github PR 3](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/8965), or even for the IL `OpCodes` - [github issue for OpCodes.Ldind_I8](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/8682))

Created a new issue for docs [@github](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/9139).

**UPD**

As written in [the answer by @Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76669499/2501279) there is another piece of documentation which [explains the usage](https://github.com/trylek/runtime/blob/e959fb5443cc016557de6dd300196cfa9d64e4a0/docs/design/specs/Ecma-335-Augments.md) of the `constrained` in this case.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That certainly clears up a lot of my confusions. I would accept it, but the answer to the actual titular question is still unclear to me. `.constrained` on a `callvirt` exists to ensure value and reference types are both handled correctly by the same `callvirt`. Here though, I don't see why boxing or anything like that would ever happen. Essentially, my question is still what is actually being checked by `.constrained` in this context?

Comment: @Tacodiva Was glad to help! Also opened a github issue - see the update.

Comment: True, but it still doesn't need `constrained.`, the whole point of which is to allow a single `this` parameter to be used both for value and reference types. This seems unnecessary on a `static` function, as there is no `this`.

Comment: @Charlieface valid point. TBH don't know, maybe it was repurposed to pass some kind of "self" type parameter so the actual method can be resolved. Will wait for comments in the issue and update answer accordingly.

Comment: https://github.com/trylek/runtime/blob/e959fb5443cc016557de6dd300196cfa9d64e4a0/docs/design/specs/Ecma-335-Augments.md#ii152-static-instance-and-virtual-methods-page-177 I'm going to write an answer with this

Comment: @Charlieface great find! Will add it to the docs issue. And as I understand it says something similar to my assumption about repurposing of the `constrained`.

Comment: I'm not sure that the stuff around the JIT emitting different method bodies for when a generic type parameter is a reference/value type is relevant? That happens at runtime when IL is turned into machine code, but virtual calls vs constrained virtual calls are an IL concept

Answer (score 3):

**According to the ECMA-335 spec**, [as augmented here](https://github.com/trylek/runtime/blob/e959fb5443cc016557de6dd300196cfa9d64e4a0/docs/design/specs/Ecma-335-Augments.md) by the DotNet Runtime team, [the specification states](https://github.com/trylek/runtime/blob/e959fb5443cc016557de6dd300196cfa9d64e4a0/docs/design/specs/Ecma-335-Augments.md#ii152-static-instance-and-virtual-methods-page-177) that `static` functions on interfaces need to be called using `constrained.` so that the runtime knows which class to dispatch the method to. This is despite using `call` or `ldftn`, and not `callvirt`, as the interface alone is not enough to dispatch the method correctly, given that there is no `this` parameter.

This is a separate use of `constrained.` from its original use, which was for `callvirt` instructions, so that `this` parameters could be dispatched in the same way regardless of value/reference-types.

The documentation of `OpCodes.Constrained` has not been updated yet for this.