# Creating list of objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to change a Dataset into a List of objects. For some reason, I have this error " Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter" but I really don't know why...

What am I missing?

Thx in advance

**automate.cs**

```
public class Automate
    {
        private string SrtAutomate { get; set; }
        public string AutomateId { get; set; }
        public string MachineName { get; set; }       
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastTreatment { get; set; }
        public bool AskStop { get; set; }
        public bool AskPause { get; set; }
        public string ListeningConfiguration { get; set; }
        public string Informations { get; set; }

        public Automate(string srtAutomate, string automateId, string machineName, 
            DateTime lastUpdate, DateTime lastTreatment, bool askStop, bool askPause, string informations, string listeningConfiguration)
        {

            SrtAutomate = srtAutomate;
            AutomateId = automateId;
            MachineName = machineName;
            LastUpdate = lastUpdate;
            LastTreatment = lastTreatment;
            AskStop = askStop;
            AskPause = askPause;
            ListeningConfiguration = listeningConfiguration;
            Informations = informations;
        }
    }
```

**checkTable.cs**

```
  public static class CheckTable
    {
        public static List<Automate> GetAutomaton()
        {            
            DataSet dsAutomate;
            List<Automate> lstAutomate = new List<Automate>();

            using (var databaseConnexion = new DatabaseConnexion(Parameters.DbSrtServer, Parameters.DbSrtName, Parameters.DbSrtUser, Parameters.DbSrtPassword))
            {
                string request = "SELECT * FROM SrtAutomateStatus";

                //CONNEXION A BDD
                try { databaseConnexion.Open(); }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception($"Impossible détablir une connexion à la base : {Parameters.DbSrtName}"); }

                DatabaseParamQuery paramQuery = new DatabaseParamQuery(request);
                //RECUPERATION DES AUTOMATES
                try { dsAutomate = databaseConnexion.GetQueryResults(paramQuery); }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception($"Impossible de récuperer la liste des automates : {ex.Message}"); }
            }

            lstAutomate = dsAutomate.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Automate
            {
                SrtAutomate = dataRow.Field<string>("srtAutomate"),
                AutomateId = dataRow.Field<string>("automateId"),
                MachineName = dataRow.Field<string>("machineName"),
                LastUpdate = dataRow.Field<DateTime>("lastUpdate"),
                LastTreatment = dataRow.Field<DateTime>("lastTreatment"),
                AskStop = dataRow.Field<bool>("askStop"),
                AskPause = dataRow.Field<bool>("askPause"),
                Informations = dataRow.Field<string>("informations"),
                ListeningConfiguration = dataRow.Field<string>("isteningConfiguration")

            }).toList();

            return lstAutomate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: The line " SrtAutomate = dataRow.Field<string>("srtAutomate"),"

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception($"Impossible détablir une connexion à la base : {Parameters.DbSrtName}"); }` This is not good practice. Don't throw the base exception type - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453650/why-are-we-not-to-throw-these-exceptions At the very least don't throw away the caught exception details, use the ctor overload that allows you to pass the exception along as an inner exception.

Comment: You're `Automate` class does not have a parameterless constructor.  Either add a constructor without parameters or change your `Select` to call the existing constructor.

Comment: Ooooh ok juharr, I thought the constructor would be call by default... Thx a lot :)