# How to handle various exceptions coming from an external function

Tags: c#

How do I handle, invoke exceptions from the add function.
The external function will throw two different exceptions depending on the conditions.
I would like to handle each of these exceptions differently in main.
Thanks for helps.

My example code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                add(0, 0);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if(Exception 1){
                    //...
                }
                if(Exception 2){
                    //...
                }               
            }          
        }

        public static int add (int a, int b)
        {
            int result = a + b;
            if (result == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception 1");
            }
            if(result > 10)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception 2");
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Do not throw `System.Exception` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453650/why-are-we-not-to-throw-these-exceptions))

Comment: Do not use exceptions for control of flow ([link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why))

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the message you assign in the add method, and then check the condition inside the main or another place you want The code with a solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            add(0, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch");

            if (ex.Message == "Exception 1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            }
            if (ex.Message == "Exception 2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2");
            }
        }
    }



public static int add(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    if (result == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception 1");
    }
    if (result > 10)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception 2");
    }
    return result;
}
```